# Redirect to different pages based on previous page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes, laravel-5

Imagine you have a method in controller, like storing a new company.
Also imagine we can create new company from different pages in our site. For example, I can create a company from 2-3 pages.

Depending on where I created the company I need to have different redirects. Sometimes I need to redirect back, and sometimes to other routes.

Something like:

```
if ($previousRoute === 'companies.index') { 
    return redirect()->back();
} else {
    return redirect()->route('someroute');
}
```

I guess I can't get the route name wher user came from. If I check referrer url then in case I change route URL everything will be broken so I want to rely on route names instead. Plus, the solution having many "if-s" or a "switch" is kind of weird, it will pollute the code.

Also wildcard support is needed. 
Some kind of route map with redirects or something like this.

Any advice how to implement this?

Comment: Since I'm guessing you're POSTing to the controller action, why can't you just pass a value that indicates whether or not you should be redirected back? And you can just include that value on the forms needed (since you said you have 2-3 pages that do that, I assume you can adjust the forms on each one as it suits you). The approach you seek doesn't have reliable solutions and is overly complicated.

Comment: Awesome solution. The only thing is, right now I have a modal window with form. I show the modal when I click on different buttons and depending on where I clicked I need to redirect user to different pages. So I made 3 files: form.blade.php, modal1.blade.php and modal2.blade.php. I include form into these modals and pass them redirect_to param, and inside form I placed hidden input with this param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can compare the previous url with the url of any route. It's not the best solution and i don't know what to do with route parameters, but it can work.

```
if (URL::previous() === URL::route('companies.index')) { 
   return redirect()->back();
} else {
   return redirect()->route('someroute');
}
```

Comment: I would stick to this one, however I like Bogdan's solution as well

Answer (score 0):

A set of `if` statements (or a `switch`) will be necessary *somewhere*, since you have to make a decision.

I wouldn't rely on the referrer URL, since it will break if you ever change your routes. Like you, I prefer route names for everything since my URLs can change.

How about a session key? Set some value, then retrieve it & choose your redirect after the company is created. Something like this:

In the controller method for create company page #1

```
Session::put('create-company-method', 1);
```

Then, after the company is created

```
$flag = Session::get('create-company-method');
if ($flag===1) {
    return redirect()->route('go-here-next');
} else if ($flag===2) {
    ...
}
```

It's not pretty, but it will do the trick. Plus it has a big advantage: you can make the session values whatever you want, so if you need to add additional information for making the decision, go ahead. You need wildcards? Set the session key however you like to pass that information along.

Comment: Storing values in a session is just as unreliable as using the passed referrer, because a user can have multiple tabs open in the browser, all of them sharing the same session. Just as the referrer can be spoofed or missing, you can't be sure that the previous page was the one that set the session value.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't unterstand if you have any "logic" behind the routing back after you save the `Company`. In one of my apps I needed to be able to edit an address and redirect either back to the previous URL or back to the index page.

If that's the case in your application there is a fairly simple and clean solution to this.

We are elavating Laravel `redirect()->intented()` function.

In your `GET` function (e.g. `getCreate`) we are setting the intented URL to the previous URL if it isn't the same as the URL itself:

```
($request->fullUrl() != URL::previous()) ? session()->set('url.intended', URL::previous()) : null;
// url.intended is the same key that is used be Laravels intented function
```

Now within your `POST` method (e.g. `postCreate`) you can just return a redirect to the intended URL like this:

```
return redirect()->intended('AddressController@getIndex');
// The string within intended() defines where you want to be redirected if there is no session key is found
```