# laravel: redirect->back() returns last page not base page

Tags: laravel, redirect

hi and thanks for response.
I have a pay operation in user panel and after successful pay want to redirect to panel so use:

```
                return redirect()->back();
```

after pay. but if user clicks and opens a url from panel in new page and then starts payment operation, will redirected to that page not panel.

> the point is that sometimes panel url may be diffrent and i want
>   laravel to detect url that request form is submitted

how to resolve this problem?

Comment: redirect to that url (ijn this case your panel url)

Comment: I want to laravel detects url because of in some cases panel url may be deffrent

Comment: please elaborate what your panel url might be with some example

Comment: some times panel url is example.com/panel and sometimes /panel/page or /panel/edit?1 and ....

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your route below way, because when you are open the link on your second tab then redirect->back() is not working so, you define the one static route and redirect for the same.

```
   return Redirect::to('some/path');
```

Comment: I want to laravel detects url because of in some cases panel url may be deffrent

Answer (score 1):

I suppose in this situation you may want to submit the form with the URL of the current page with appropriate URL parameters?

if this is the case, simply add the following to the bottom of your form in your view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_url" value="{{ url()->full() }}">
```

then, in your controller you may access it as:

```
$request->form_url;
```

This will give you the ability to persist the URL that the form submitted from in future logic.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the user to their panel.

```
return redirect()->route(“user_panel”, [“user” => Auth::user()];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return redirect()->back();
```

is used for u want to go last page .

```
 return redirect()->route('login');
```

here login is your route name where you want ot redirect. follow url for more details.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects

Comment: ok sometimes panel url may be diffrent and i want laravel to detect url thant request form is submitted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896355/redirect-to-different-pages-based-on-previous-page-in-laravel
follow this this will help you

Comment: thanks. but I cant get my answer from this post: how can I get submitted form url of request? its the key to resolve it

Comment: URL::current()
it will return the current url
after thet you can add the condition like this way
if (URL::previous() === URL::route('companies.index')) { 
   return redirect()->back();
} else {
   return redirect()->route('someroute');
}

Comment: URL::current() returns form action url and its not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this recently , so I put that base page url in session in the controller , then you can get it from session and redirect to this url whenever you want.